# Procedimiento almacenado APS.NET MVC que devuelva un arreglo

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Como puedo crear un procedimiento almacenado que me muestre las deducciones de los empleados

necesito un resultado asi : donde muestra la deduccion uniforme[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla empleados 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta la tabla deducciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la tabla Detalle de deducciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres un query que te retorne todos los datos que se muestran en la pagina? De ser así te falta mostrar la tabla empleados y si no es que otras mas.

Comment: Si tienes razon olvide ponerla , pero ya la puse.   No importa que no me muestre el sueldo o puesto mas que todo es el id del empleado , nombre y las deducciones

Comment: creo que las primeras 2 imágenes están repetidas.

Comment: ok bro ya subi las tres tablas , Tbl_Empleados, Tbl_Deducciones, Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado

Comment: Sugerencia: Si la información es del tipo read-only, te sugiero que la trabajes en una VISTA en el SQL server, EntityFramework la trabajará con toda naturalidad y te será más sencillo hacer búsquedas y filtros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si esto es lo que necesites pero en cuestión de los joins entre tablas, esta sería la forma:

```
Select emp.EmpId as Codigo, emp.EmpNombre + ' ' + emp.EmpApellido as Empleado,
td.DedValor as Uniforme FROM Tbl_Empleados emp INNER JOIN Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado
tde ON emp.EmpId = tde.EmpId INNER JOIN Tbl_Deducciones td ON tde.DedId = td.DedId
```

> Puedes usar Left Join en vez de Inner join para mostrar todos los datos cuando algunos sean nulos. Por ejemplo DevValor.

Creo que podrias utilizar un pivote para lo que necesitas en cuestion de poner todas las deducciones en una misma fila, desconozco cuantas deducciones son, puse 5 como ejemplo, no se si te vaya a funcionar la consulta, solo es un ejemplo:

```
        SELECT emp.EmpId AS Codigo
        ,emp.EmpNombre + ' ' + emp.EmpApellido AS Empleado
            ,[1] AS Ded1
            ,[2] AS Ded2
            ,[3] AS Ded3
            ,[4] AS Ded4
            ,[5] AS Ded5
            FROM Tbl_Empleados emp
            INNER JOIN(
            SELECT * FROM ( SELECT empId, DetDedEmpValor, DetId 
       FROM Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado) I 
        PIVOT(MAX(DetDedEmpValor) FOR DetID IN (
                    [1]
                    ,[2]
                    ,[3]
                    ,[4]
                    ,[5]
                    )) P) I ON emp.EmpId = I.EmpId
```

Pruebalo y me cuentas.

Comment: Bueno mas que todo es que  me muestre el empleado y todas su deducciones en una sola linea horizontal así como en la primera imagen, no necesaria me tiene que mostrar la deducción  uniforme , si no que todas las deducciones que tiene en esa tabla  esos dos empleados o todos

Comment: Puedes utilizar un pivote si no me equivoco, para agrupar todas las deducciones en una misma fila, modifique mi respuesta, pruebalo y me cuentas.

Comment: El EmpId me dice que es ambiguo

Comment: Como dije antes, solo es un codigo de ejemplo se me puede ir mal algun nombre de tabla o de columna debido a que tu no pusiste el codigo como tal de tus tablas, pusiste imagenes así que tengo que transcribir todo, modifique mi respuesta del query del pivote, espero esta vez si te funcione, un saludo amigo.

Comment: Bro perfecto ya, pero que pasaría si agregan una nueva deducción sera que hay algo que me la agregue automáticamente ?

Comment: Por ejemplo tu ahorita en el codigo que te puse tienes 5 deducciones osea que tu DedId en tu tabla de deducciones llega hasta el 5, en caso de que tuvieras una numero 6 o 7, solo la agregas a la lista del pivote para que la ordene en base a ese id(solo agregarias el nuevo DedId a la lista) te recomiendo leer la documentación sobre Pivot en sql server [Pivot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: y para crear un vista con ese query como seria ?

Comment: es que necesito llevar eso a  mi proyecto en asp.net mvc 5